# Retrieving unique list of keys from nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have this dictionary.

```
d = {'match1': {'player1': 57, 'player2': 38},
     'match2': {'player1': 42, 'player3': 9},
     'match3': {'player2': 41, 'player3': 91, 'player4': 63}}
```

I want a loop to run with index `player1, player2, player3, player4.` 
How do I write the loop structure? There might be many more **players**.

I tried:

```
for i in ["player1", "player2", "player3", "player4"]:
```

But this only works for exactly 4 players. What to do if players are more or less?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to *construct* the key by appending a numeric suffix to a constant string. Use `str.format` for that:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    key = 'player{}'.format(i)
    print(key)   # player1, player2, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all matches, collect all encountered player names to set. Iterate over that set afterwards.

```
players = {player for match_name in d for player in d[match_name]]}
for player in players:
    print(player)
```